# What is the size of $\text {Aut}\ (\Gamma)\ $?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, automorphism-group, graph-isomorphism

> Consider the graph $\Gamma$

[image]

What is the size of $\text {Aut}\ (\Gamma)\ $?

I think the size of $\text {Aut}\ (\Gamma)$ is $8$ since $1$ can go to either $1$ or $4$, $2$ can go to either $2$ or $6$ and $3$ can go to either $3$ or $5.$ Am I right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd look at its complement.

Comment: Is there any relation between $\text {Aut}\ (\Gamma)$ and $\text {Aut}\ \left (\Gamma^c \right )\ $?

Comment: @Anacardium They are the same.

Comment: @Angina Seng can you help me in this regard? I am a new to this subject.

Comment: @Anacardium: I’ll second **Angina Seng**’s advice: the complement is very simple, and its automorphism group is very easy to identify. (You’ve identified the possible vertex interchanges but missed the fact that some of them are interdependent; this shows up much more clearly in the complement.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I found that if $\text {Aut}\ \left (\Gamma^c \right )$ acts on the set of all vertices $\{1,2,\cdots, 6 \}$ then $\text {Stab}\ (1) = \left \{\text {id}, (2\ 6)\ (3\ 5) \right \}.$ Also it is clear that $\{1 \} \subseteq \text {Orb}\ (1) \subseteq \{1,2,4,6 \}.$ So by orbit-stabilizer theorem the possible orders of $\text {Aut}\ \left (\Gamma^c \right ) = 2,4,6$ or $8.$

Comment: What I just observe is that $1$ cannot map to $2$ and by symmetry $1$ cannot map to $6$ as well @BrianM.Scott. So $1$ can either go to $1$ or $4.$

Comment: There are exactly two elements sending $1$ to $4$ which are $(1\ 4)$ and $(1\ 4)\ (2\ 6)\ (3\ 5).$ So $\text {Orb} (1) = \{1,4 \}.$

Comment: Hence by orbit-stabilizer theorem it follows that $$\left \lvert \text {Aut}\ \left (\Gamma^c \right ) \right \rvert = 2 \times 2 = 4.$$

Comment: So from the technique of the proof of orbit-stabilizer theorem it follows that $$\text {Aut} \left (\Gamma^c \right ) = \left \{\text {id}, (1\ 4), (2\ 6)\ (3\ 5), (1\ 4)\ (2\ 6)\ (3\ 5) \right \}.$$ In other words $$\text {Aut} \left (\Gamma^c \right ) \cong \Bbb Z/ 2 \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z.$$ @Angina Seng please check my argument.

Comment: @Anacardium That's right. The complement consists of two disjoint paths, one with one  edge and the other with three edges. The automorphisms either fix the vertices of each path or flip the path around. There are four automorphisms.

Comment: @Anacardium: Yes, that’s it. (Sorry to be so slow, but I was asleep when you got it.)